# MS Access Serializing Complex SQL Fields?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

It's not really complex.  Basically, some data are stored as normal "Text" field but uses the built in Combo Box as Display Control.  This is all fine and good except now when I try to export all the data in VBA, it's throwing an error everytime it reach that column because apparently it can't serialize the complex data type.

```
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from my_table", dbOpenSnapshot)
    msgbox rs(1)
```

Here are the field property

[image: Field Properties]

Comment: Are you using sharepoint? If not, look-up in tables is an anti-feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this article:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258183(v=office.12).aspx](http://How%20to%3a%20Manipulate%20Multivalued%20Fields%20With%20DAO)

> Multivalued fields are represented as Recordset objects in DAO. The
>   recordset for a field is a child of the recordset for the table that
>   contains the multivalued field...

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It worked.  It wasn't the complex structure, it was the child recordSet object that threw it off.